# Could not connect to SMTP host - Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, email, authentication

I am trying to send Email with Spring MVC.
But everytime i run my code it throws an error:

**Nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.mailtrap.io, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.mailtrap.io, port: 25;**

Samples from my code:

*dispatcher-servlet.xml*

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.mailtrap.io"/>
        <property name="port" value="25"/>
        <property name="username" value="30f4d***44754"/>
        <property name="password" value="16a83***17add6"/>
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Controller class:

```
@Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/emailForm",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String doSendEmail() {
        SimpleMailMessage email = new SimpleMailMessage();
        email.setTo("key@wp.pl");
        email.setSubject("LOL");
        email.setText("heh");

        // sends the e-mail
        mailSender.send(email);

        // forwards to the view named "Result"
        return "Result";
    }
```

I know that method should be POST but i want to only test it so i just did GET.
When I checked my props in SMTP Test Tool it works. Only in code it doesnt work.

Comment: see if your port 25  is not already used by anything/open. `netstat -aon | findstr 25` .
Terminate any process that is using it by `taskkill /F /PID {process_id}`. check if you have mail server running or not, you might need to specify logins of mail server. Simplest test would be run `FakeSmtp`[http://nilhcem.com/FakeSMTP/] to see your code works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a firewall between your location and mailtrap.io that's blocking port 25.  Port 25 is commonly blocked to deter spamming.

Try another port mailtrap supports instead of 25 (e.g., 2525).